# Yellow stripe on the header of the frame (TexStudio)

Tags: pdf, texstudio, viewers

I have recently downloaded TexStudio, and imported my project from Overleaf into it. Now, when I run the preview, I get the following behaviour: The part, where the header was supposed to be, has a yellowish color on it, which is only visible in the viewer (so it must be a problem with TexStudio), but not on the actual file. How can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: It isn't a problem, it highlights some portion of the output which is related to the code where your cursor is located.

Comment: I have tried it now, and unfortunately, it isn't the case :( (my highlight color is blue)

Comment: It is strange. This yellowish color is exactly the default highlight color. Is it permanent? Does it appear only when you navigate between source code and PDF viewer? Does it appear when you visualize the PDF on an external PDF viewer? If not, I'd say it comes from the template (probably not, since you said it worked on Overleaf).

Comment: It is permanent on the PDF-viewer of TexStudio. When I export it and open it via e.g. Acrobat, the yellow stripe disappears. The slides I have been having this problem with all are in a group environment with \setbeamertemplate{headline}[default] in them.